# Setting up C++ developing environment

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ dev and spent last months trying out solidity stuff but defintely want to try EOS now.

How do I get started to understand all the terms and various parts of EOS ?

I've seen gas works differently here and you need to have big quantities of gas to publish your contract. Someone can explain me how does it works ?

What software do I need except from my dev framework ?

Thanks everyone

Comment: There are too many questions here. Please edit and focus on the technical side. What is it specifically that you are experiencing difficulty with?

Comment: I don't get how to deploy basically. I can write my C++ code and then what ? 
I guess to publish it I would need a blockchain running (private for testing purposes) and a node connected to it. Once you got everything up and running I guess you will deploy on the blockchain and then use the smart contract published with your front end I guess. 

This is how it works ? 
If yes what I need to look for to start setting up everything ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a development environment is simple, just follow the first page of the wiki, here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get started on EOS you can do so by running your own single node testnet on your local machine. I recommend using Docker for this.

There's a community documentation site called [EOSDocs.io](https://eosdocs.io) which I suggest you go to which will run you through starting your own blockchain, keys, accounts, compiling and deploying contracts.

There's also the [EOS Developer telegram channel](https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=s1139062279_6533984445038805810) too.